# Mysql, функция в переменной

Tags: php, mysql

Доброго времени суток. 
Возможно ли в mysql в селектах использовать функции, имена которых сохранены в таблицах?

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял вы ищите eval() mysql, сам не пользовал - по любому это не очень хороший способ программировать, но вот есть вариант: [MySQL eval()](http://code.openark.org/blog/mysql/mysql-eval)

Comment: Да, но не подходит. Сильно уж напряжно будет для сервера.
Задача такова, есть база дынных интернет магазина, в ней есть таблица пользователей, таблица с базовыми ценами на товар, таблица с типами наценок на товар(например: +процент или +статическое число), и связная таблица с ценой, пользователем, и типом наценки. На одной цене для каждого пользователя установлена разная наценка.
Товаров(цен) примерно 80 000, а пользователей примерно 600
Каждому пользователю нужно показывать именно его наценку. И еще пользователю нужен фильтр по цене. Как это реализовать не имею пока понятия.

Comment: JOIN-ами, другого варианта я не вижу. Если запрос будет очень тяжелым можно подумать о переходе на более производительную базу, например vertica.

Answer (score 0):

если я верно понял описанную в комментарии к [другому ответу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/430824/178576) схему базы данных, то вот такой примерно запрос, надеюсь, поможет в поиске правильного решения:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f50a5/2)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
create table polz (id int, imja varchar(100));
create table tovar (id int, imja varchar(100), cena int);
create table nacenka (id int, tip enum("procent", "plussumma"), znachenie int);
create table svjaz (id int, polz int, tovar int, nacenka int);

insert into polz values (1, "вася"), (2, "петя");
insert into tovar
 values (1, "сайт", 1000), (2, "сервер", 2000), (3, "ботинки", 3000),
 (4, "счастье", 4000);
insert into nacenka values (1, "procent", 5), (2, "plussumma", 33);
insert into svjaz values (1, 1, 1, 1), (2, 2, 2, 2), (3, 1, 3, 1);
```

**Query 1**:

```
select p.imja, t.imja,
 if(n.tip is null, t.cena,
  if(n.tip = "procent",
   t.cena * (1 + n.znachenie/100),
   t.cena + n.znachenie)) as cena
 from polz p
 cross join tovar t
 left join svjaz s on s.tovar = t.id and s.polz = p.id
 left join nacenka n on n.id = s.nacenka
 order by 1, 2
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f50a5/2/0)**:

```
| imja |    imja | cena |
|------|---------|------|
| вася | ботинки | 3150 |
| вася |    сайт | 1050 |
| вася |  сервер | 2000 |
| вася | счастье | 4000 |
| петя | ботинки | 3000 |
| петя |    сайт | 1000 |
| петя |  сервер | 2033 |
| петя | счастье | 4000 |
```

Comment: Да, можно и так, вариант хороший, но... Вариантов наценок примерно 20, да еще между пользователями работает 3-х уровневая реферальная система. Поэтому было решено написать функция на mysql которая принимает два аргумента, id user и и тип наценки, функция рекурсивно считает результат и возвращает его. По производительности прогнозов не дам, но посмотрим. Если будет уж сильно тяжко, буду искать другие алгоритмы.

Comment: сделал правку коммента...

Comment: а конечная цель какова? вам нужо лишь получить итоговую цену? или помимо цены нужно получать и формулу подсчёта этой цены в математическом виде?

Comment: формула по сути не нужна, нужна итоговая цена, и в случае успешной продажи, нужно пересчитать цену в обратном направлении, для подсчета комиссионных  для каждого пользователя связанных в цепочке.

Comment: тогда, мне думается, имеет смысл (для ускорения выборки информации) слегка отступить от канонов нормализации б.д. и поддерживать кросс-таблицу *пользователь+товар+цена*, в которую вносить изменения с помощью, например, триггеров, привязанных к «журналу совершённых операций», в который будут заноситься факты продаж, изменений наценок и т.п.

Comment: Согласен на 100%, так сформирована базовая цена, но цена на сайте в трех валютах, и курс каждый день меняется, при обновлении курса, будет идти очень тяжелый (upgrade) цен. 80000 товаров, 600 юзеров...